# How do you tell Dafny to use a lemma when validating termination

Tags: terminate, hint, dafny

Dafny makes use of a decreases clause to verify that a recursive function terminates. When verification fails can Dafny be given a hint, in this case in the form of a lemma.  How to I tell Dafny to use the lemma when checking that the decreases clause actually decreases?

```
datatype List<T> = Nil | Cons(head:T, tail:List<T>) 
datatype Twee = Node(value : int, left : Twee, right : Twee) | Leaf
function rotateLeft(t:Twee) :Twee
{
    match t 
       case Leaf => t 
       case Node(v,Node(vl,ll,rl),r) => Node(vl,ll,Node(v,rl,r))
       case Node(v,Leaf,r) => Node(v,Leaf,r)
}
  function Leftheight(t:Twee) :(h:nat) decreases t
{
  match t 
    case Leaf => 0 
    case Node(_,l,_) =>  1+Leftheight(l)
}     
lemma {:induction ll, rl, r} decreasesHint(v:int, vl:int, ll:Twee,rl:Twee,r:Twee)
   ensures   Leftheight(Node(v,Node(vl,ll,rl),r)) == 
           1+ Leftheight(Node(vl,ll, Node(v,rl,r)))  {} 
function rotateAllLeft(t:Twee) :Twee
    decreases t, Leftheight(t)
{
    match t 
       case Leaf => Leaf 
       case Node(v,Leaf,r) => Node(v,Leaf,rotateAllLeft(r))  //decrases t
       case Node(v,Node(vl,ll,rl),r) => //{ decreasesHint(v,vl,ll,rl,r);}
                  rotateAllLeft(rotateLeft(Node(v,Node(vl,ll,rl),r)))     
}
```

Sorry for such a long example but this is the first time I have wanted to give hints for checking termination. The error `failure to decrease termination measure` occurs on the last line `rotateAllLeft(rotateLeft(Node(v,Node(vl,ll,rl),r)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a lemma from inside an expression. Just use a semicolon to separate the lemma call from the rest of the expression.

```
      case Node(v,Node(vl,ll,rl),r) =>
        decreasesHint(v,vl,ll,rl,r);
        rotateAllLeft(rotateLeft(Node(v,Node(vl,ll,rl),r)))
```

Note that this does not completely solve your termination problems, because your `decreases` annotation is `t, Leftheight(t)`, which means that recursive calls must either make `t` smaller, or *leave `t` the same* and make the left height smaller. But this recursive call does not leave `t` the same. I tried changing your annotation to just `decreases Leftheight(t)`, which accepted this `case`, but gave an error on the previous `case`. Maybe you can find a way around that.

Comment: Many thanks I had tried adding it there but had also added { ..  }.